# automatic processing of numerical results in `Plot`

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, numerics

First I want to solve an equation $F(x,y)=0$ for $y$ by supplying a value of $x$. (suppose obtaining the analytic form of $y(x)$ is too difficult) Then I want to plot root $y$ (numerically calculated) as a function of $x$ by using the following:

```
Plot[y /. FindRoot[.../.{x->x0},{y, 0.2}],{x0, 0, 1}]
```

and I got something like the following

[image]

I omit `...` here since it is terribly complicated. **Update**: F(x,y) is of the form

$\sum_{n,m}a_{m,n}x^ny^m$

and $m$ and $n$ can be as high as 19, which basically makes `Solve` impractical.

The result is satisfying except a small number of points near 1.0. Setting another initial starting value of $y$ in `FindRoot` might be an option but it is very tedious and often I cannot find a value of $y$ that fits the whole range of $x$.

My question is: suppose I stick with the initial value of $y$, is there a way to just eliminate that anomaly point after I `Plot` the numerical results? Or is there a better way to deal with this kind of numerical problem in general?

Comment: For some functions you can use the previously found root to start looking for the next. But I can't know how your function behaves since it isn't supplied.

Comment: @Anon,sounds like a good idea, could you write some code on it? For the function, it is rational function very similar to a Pade approximant. But it is too complicated to be readable so I didn't put it in the question.

Comment: @wdg You could try to use the form `FindRoot[...,{x,xstart,xmin,xmax}]` and restrict the search to [0,1]. Maybe this helps.

Comment: @halirutan, it does help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `NDSolve` to create an interpolation often works well.  Hard to tell if it will work with your function.

```
With[{f = x^2 y + y^3 - 1/3},
 sol = NDSolveValue[{Dt[f == 0, x] /. y -> y[x], 
    y[0] == (y /. FindRoot[f /. x -> 0, {y, 0.6}])}, y, {x, 0, 1}]]
(* InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 1.}}, <>] *)

Plot[sol[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: A very nice trick!

Answer (score 2):

In case it helps to determine the new initial search value from the old, which is sometimes the case, it can be done like this:

```
f[x_, y_] := ArcTan[x + y]
x0 = 0;
Plot[(x0 = FindRoot[f[x, y], {x, x0}][[1, 2]]), {y, -100, 100}]
```

Comment: This method works well if the value of `y` is changing slowly from step to step, for example when creating a table of values for `ListPlot`. However, `Plot` will sample the function at `y` values which hop around all over the place as it goes through the recursive refinement process, so I don't think this method is reliable.

Comment: @SimonWoods You are absolutely right! I stored the y-values in this example using `Sow` and the largest differences were very large which is not something I had anticipated. It's still better than using a static initial value, I think, but as you say it's better to use `Table` and `ListPlot` to do it this way.

Answer (score 2):

***Like this:?***

Here I give F(x,y)= Abs@x + Abs@(x + y)-1

```
Plot[y /. Solve[Abs@x + Abs@(x + y) == 1, y, Reals] // 
       Evaluate, {x, -2, 2}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

***Another methods:***

Using the `ContourPlot` command

```
ContourPlot[Abs[x] + Abs[x + y] == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Frame -> False, Axes -> True]
```

Comment: `ContourPlot` is a good idea. In fact I often use `ContourPlot` to verify numerical results obtained through other means.