# How do I feed data points into an equation to solve NUMERICALLY?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, numerics, interpolation

I start with this equation and solve it numerically for $z(x,y)$ in the range $1 < x < 5$ and $1 < y < 5$:

$$ \frac{3}{xyz} - 2x - 3y - 5z = 0 $$

Then using the data points of $z$ above, I want to solve for this special condition:

$$ x + y + z  = 0  $$

Then I want to plot a graph of $y(x)$. Everything must be done numerically.

```
eqn1 = 3/(x y z) - 2 x - 3 y - 5 z   == 3
ContourPlot3D[Evaluate[eqn1], {x, 1, 5}, {y, 1, 5}, {z, 0, -5}]

fulldomain = 
  Table[z /. Solve[eqn1, z, Method -> Reduce], {x, 1, 5, 1}, {y, 1, 5,
     1}] ;

eqn2 = x + y + z  == 0 


special = 
 Table[y /. Solve[eqn2 /. fulldomain, y, Method -> Reduce], {x, 1, 5, 
   1}]

ifun = Interpolation[special]
Plot[ifun[x], {x, 1, 5}, Epilog -> Map[Point, special]]
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eliminate z from two equations in x, y, z and plot y as a function of x](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58786/eliminate-z-from-two-equations-in-x-y-z-and-plot-y-as-a-function-of-x)

Comment: it is NOT a duplicate, as the methods used in that were to solve it analytically to get an expression. I realized that took a long time, so I tried a numerical method instead.

Comment: I strongly reinforced my point by saying everything must be done numerically. That is the big difference between this and that post.

Comment: @b.gatessucks It manages to generate the table of values "fulldomain", but fails to plot it.

Comment: Using your equations and `Solve` and `Eliminate`, I get a symbolic solution for `y` as a function of `x` very quickly. Plotting the symbolic `y[x]` for `1 <= x <= 5` is also quick. Where are you encountering any slow response from _Mathematica_?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a difficulty with the statement of the problem.  Generally the problem can be solved as shown below.  In this case there is a stipulation that $1 < x < 5$ and $1 < y < 5$.  Unfortunately the solution to the system does not satisfy these constraints (also shown below).

If we agree to use only numerical techniques and pretend that `Solve` (nor `NSolve`) will not produce solutions, then `FindRoot` is the way to find a single solution.  The best way to make an interpolating function for `y` as a function of `x` is via `NDSolve` and a differential-algebraic equation.  Below I assume that the equations `eqn1` and `eqn2` actually define `y` as a unique function of `x`.  In some systems, this will not be true, and one may have to do more work to determine which branch or branches are to be computed.

We have to find the first point of the intersection with `FindRoot`. The starting point `{x, y, z} = {1, 1, 1}` for `FindRoot` may have to be tweaked for other systems.  (It's not a terribly enlightened guess for this specific case, either, but this case is easy for `FindRoot`.)

```
eqn1 = 3/(x y z) - 2 x - 3 y - 5 z == 3;
eqn2 = x + y + z == 0;

ic = FindRoot[eqn1 && eqn2 && x == 1, {x, 1}, {y, 1}, {z, 1}]  (* initial values for x, y, z *)

yIFN = NDSolveValue[
  {x'[t] ==  1, {x[1], y[1], z[1]} == ({x, y, z} /. ic),
   {eqn1, eqn2} /. v : (x | y | z) :> v[t]}, y, {t, 1, 5}]
(*
  {x -> 1., y -> 0.890705, z -> -1.8907}

  InterpolatingFunction[{{1., 5.}}, <>]
*)

Plot[yIFN[x], {x, 1, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that by the initial value problem given to `NDSolve`, `x` and `t` are the same.

Note also that **`0 < y < 1`** -- that is, it does not satisfy the constraint in the problem.  Here is another view of the problem in `x y z` space:

```
Show[
 ContourPlot3D[
  Evaluate@{eqn1, eqn2}, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, {z, 0, -5}, 
  ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5], AxesLabel -> Automatic],
 ParametricPlot3D[{x, yIFN[x], -x - yIFN[x]}, {x, 1, 5}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.02]}],
 PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The intersection of the surfaces defined by `eqn1` and `eqn2` lies outside the region $1 < x < 5$, $1 < y < 5$.

---

*Edit: On setting up `NDSolve`*

To use `NDSolveValue`, I needed to change simple variables `x`, `y`, `z` to functions `x[t]`, `y[t]`, `z[t]`.  One could simply retype them, but I tend to do it programmatically (if it's convenient -- as you get more familiar with a system, what seem convenient expands).  This saves headaches on typos (for me at least) and updating changes to the equations.

[Rules](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Rules.html) and [Patterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Patterns.html) (`->`, `:>`, etc. see [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616) for a index of such signs) are fundamental objects.  Function definitions are stored as rules in a functions [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DownValues.html).  [Many functions return them](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18706#18706), such as `FindRoot` above.  The first two links of this paragraph have tutorials and documentation pages for learning about these important objects.

The rules in `ic` replace the variables `x`, `y`, `z` by the coordinates of the point of intersection of the two surfaces `eqn1`, `eqn2` with the plane `x == 1` that was found by `FindRoot`:

```
{x'[t] == 1, {x[1], y[1], z[1]} == ({x, y, z} /. ic),...}
(*
  {x'[t] == 1, {x[1], y[1], z[1]} == {1., 0.890705, -1.8907},...}
*)
```

Since $dx/dt = 1$ and $x(1) = 1$, `NDSolveValue` will compute the function $x$ to be equal to $x(t) = t$.  In other words, `t` is being used as a dummy variable to represent `x` along the intersection curve of the two surfaces.  One can get more or less of the intersection by changing the integration domain `{t, 1, 5}` in `NDSolveValue` to whatever range of `x` is desired.

To convert the terms of the equations from variables to functions, the following rule was used, which I will display in [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FullForm.html):

```
v : (x | y | z) :> v[t] // FullForm
(*
  RuleDelayed[Pattern[v, Alternatives[x, y, z]], v[t]]
*)
```

[`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RuleDelayed.html) has the form

```
pattern :> replacement formula
```

The [`Pattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pattern.html) I used has the form

```
name : pattern object
```

The name is a variable `v` that is used in the replacement formula to represent an expression that matches the pattern object.  The pattern object in this case is the [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Alternatives.html) pattern

```
x | y | z
```

It matches the expression `x`, the expression `y`, or the expression `z`.  The replacement formula is `v[t]`.  So when `v` matches `x`, the symbol `x` is replaced by `x[t]`; when `v` matches `y`, the symbol `y` is replaced by `y[t]`; and so on.  The second line below in the output shows the complete result:

```
{{eqn1, eqn2}, {eqn1, eqn2} /. v : (x | y | z) :> v[t]}
(*
  {{-2 x    - 3 y    + 3 / (x    y    z)    - 5 z    == 3, x    + y    + z    == 0},
   {-2 x[t] - 3 y[t] + 3 / (x[t] y[t] z[t]) - 5 z[t] == 3, x[t] + y[t] + z[t] == 0}}
*)
```

Comment: why do you put &&x==1  into the list of boundary conditions for FindRoot?

Comment: @user44840 Initially because it's an end point of the region $1 < x < 5$ -- I called it the "first point."  Afterwards, I realized I assumed there was an endpoint at $x = 1$.  In some cases one might have to do some checking to find the endpoint.  In other words, `FindRoot` is finding the point of intersection of your two surfaces and the plane `x == 1`.

Comment: I don't really understand the yIFN line of code and in the IC line of code shouldn't there also be && y==1? (since first point also consists of $y=1$)

Comment: *IC:* There are three unknowns so one should use three equations (`eqn1`, eqn2`, `x == 1`).  To add a fourth equation would make the system overdetermined. If `y == 1` is added the system becomes inconsistent (no solution). *yIFN:* You might have to be more specific.  What's the trouble, differential equations in general, differential-algebraic equations, the first argument, `NDSolve`?  The first argument can be inspected piecemeal.  Try evaluating `{eqn1, eqn2} /. v : (x | y | z) :> v[t]` to see that it replaces `x` by `x[t]` etc.  I'm not sure what to address.

Comment: What does  v : (x | y | z) :> v[t]} mean? I don't understand the syntax at all

Comment: @user44840 I've tried to address the issues in the comments in the edit to the answer.  Let me know if further clarification is needed.  Thanks.

Comment: I used the same trick [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34599/automatic-processing-of-numerical-results-in-plot/34609#34609) and in the second method [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/49131/how-to-use-findroot-to-solve-an-equation-containing-a-parameter/49181#49181). I used a different approach [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27913/solve-trigonometric-equation/27984#27984).

Comment: OK I've read through all of the part on Edit, which I understand. However, in the YIFN part of the code, v[t] was never defined earlier (v is just a name for the pattern, right?)